# Building DBD::SQlite on redhat Linux 64 bit

Tags: linux, perl, sqlite, perl-module

I am trying to build DBD::SQlite on perl 5.12 on Redhat Linux 64 bit. Make Nakefile.PL is finishing with no error.

But when I am running the test by make test. I am getting follwing errors

```
gcc -c  -I. -I/mount_point/sdk/perl/5.10.0/lib/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT \
    -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include    \
    -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -O2    \
    -DVERSION='"1.35"' -DXS_VERSION='"1.35"' -fPIC                   \
    "-I/mu/apps/perl/5.10.0/lib/CORE"  -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3          \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE           \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DNDEBUG=1 -DHAVE_USLEEP=1       \
    SQLite.c 

In file included from /usr/include/features.h:352,
                 from /usr/include/sys/types.h:27,
                 from /mu/apps/perl/5.10.0/lib/CORE/perl.h:587,
                 from SQLiteXS.h:11,
                 from SQLite.xs:3:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [SQLite.o] Error 1
```

It seems that it is not able to find the stubs from 32 bit env. Can anyone help me please to  get this straight. Its first time that I am encountering with 64 bit. I would appreciate that if someone can redirect me to general pit and falls too.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is /mu/sdk? You seem to run a custom setup, add the details how it differs from a standard one. You mention Perl 5.12 in the prose and 5.10 in the error message, this information conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for a naive assumption, but are you sure you have glibc-devel package installed?

```
# rpm -qf /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h
glibc-devel-2.14.1-14.14.1.i686
```

Comment: On a 64-bit system, that file is in package `glibc-devel-32bit` (here: `glibc-devel-32bit-2.14.1-123.1.x86_64`), but installing that would be merely doctoring the symptoms. I have the strong suspicion the OP has several Perls and is not compiling against the correct one.